Setting dynamic height to Rich Text Editor control in PowerApps Form
I have a RTE control in my PowerApps form. Now I want the control height should set dynamically based on the content it has. I am using below formula to auto update height, but the issue is each time the content is added into the RTE control, it updates the height along with some additional whitespace. The Additional white space is getting increased more and more as we keep on adding more content.
(CountRows(MatchAll(PlainText(RTEControl.HtmlText),"\n"))*25)

Please help me in solving this .
Thanks in advance.

Why are you multiplying by 25, not adding it?
